# PHPExcel plugin in heroku

Tags: php, heroku, phpexcel, php-extension

How do I install PHPExcel plugin in a herokuapp?   Any inputs will be highly appreciated!

I have enabled 'php_zlib extension' in the server but not able to enable 'php_zip extension'.  Is there a workaround / alternative for using PHPExcel functionality in herokuapp?

Thanks,
Subbu

Comment: Please see my response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043453/ziparchive-library-is-not-enabled-when-using-phpexcel if you're only writing xlsx workbooks